# Is there a way to get the symbols contained in a fortran .mod file?

Tags: module, fortran, symbols

I am trying to compile a homemade fortran code with many different libraries and I get a conflict  error:

error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name

It sounds like the name of my module already exists in one of the libraries that I call, most probably .mod file. In order to check that, I would need a tool to list the symbols defined by library, similar to `nm` for .a libraries. Does anybody know any?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? There is no standard format of mod files. Did you just try to open the file in a text editor? What happened?

Comment: I am using ifort and the .mod files are binary. They cannot be simply opened with a text editor.

Comment: In that case try to ask in the official Intel Fortran support forum, it is quite active and responsive.